# javascript server tag not well formed

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i wish to pass 2 value to invoke my script but i failed to do so it return me server tag not well formed

```
asp:LinkButton ID="lnkname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("movieTitle") %>' Width='500px' 

CommandName="cmdLink" PostBackUrl='~/videotest.aspx' 

OnClientClick="setSessionValue('video','<%#Eval("movieTitle") %>');"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("setSessionValue(\"video\", {0});", Eval("movieTitle")) %>'
```

Or even better ensure that you properly encode the movie title using the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class:

```
OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("setSessionValue(\"video\", {0});", new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Eval("movieTitle"))) %>'
```

Yeah, I agree, what a horrible mess are those WebForms. You would probably externalize this into a function in your code behind:

```
public string FormatJs(object movieTitle)
{
    return string.Format(
        "setSessionValue(\"video\", {0});", 
        new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(movieTitle)
    );
}
```

and then:

```
OnClientClick='<%# FormatJs(Eval("movieTitle")) %>'
```