# The server tag is not well formed. When passing parameters to javascript function

Tags: asp.net

Hi have always trouble with calling JavaScript function with parameters values as values bonded to the gridview. I follow [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157738/javascript-server-tag-not-well-formed) But can not used for passing `this` parameter . Below is the statement that I used in my aspx page.

```
onblur="return ValidateText(this,'<%# Eval("vehicleId") %>')"
```

But this gives me parsing error `The server tag is not well formed.` How should I call this function in design only(not from code behind).

Comment: try onblur='return ValidateText(this,<%# Eval("vehicleId") %>)'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works, but seems an HACK because I removed the enclosing quotes (anti-XHtml)

```
 onblur=<%# String.Format("return ValidateText(this, '{0}')", Eval("VehicleID")) %>
```

The problem is having `" "" "` or `' '' '` as part of the string.

This is better done (I wish it is easier in markup), in code-behind, e.g. RowDataBound or ItemDataBound

```
 control.Attributes["onblur"] = String.Format("return ValidateText(this, '{0}')", rowValue);
```

Comment: I can confirm that taking off the outer single quotes fixed it for me as well. Thanks.

Comment: Good html requires you put quote around your attributes... But you can as long as you browser supports it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the outer-most double quotes `"`, change that to single quotes `'`.

```
onblur='return ValidateText(this,'<%# Eval("vehicleId") %>')'
```

**UPDATE**

Try using `string.Format()` as mentioned in the SO question your are refering..

```
onblur='<%# System.String.Format("return ValidateText(this, \"{0}\")", Eval("vehicleId")) %>'
```